# Errors compiling a presentation with beamer class

Tags: beamer, presentations

Can anyone tell me the error(s) in this code??

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{89,1,10}
%\geometry{verbose,letterpaper}
\newcommand{\bwarrow}{\item[\color{myblue}\ding{227}]}
\newcommand{\barrow}{\item[\color{myblue}\ding{228}]}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\title[Method of Presentation]{Beautiful Presentation using Beamer}
\author{Shreeja and Rageeni} 
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Motivation} 
\begin{block} {Why Beamer????}
\end{block} 
\begin{itemize}
\barrow portability
\barrow Ease of collaboration
\barrow Free licence and community support
\barrow Content before style
\barrow Reuse LATEX code
\end{itemize}
\hyperlink{https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/miller/miller.pdf#}]{\beamergotobutton{for detail click here}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The error based on your line:

```
\hyperlink{https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/miller/miller.pdf#}]{\beamergotobutton{for detail click here}
```

First of all you should use `\href` instead of `\hyperlink`. The documentation of `hyperref` explains why:

> A simple internal link is created with `\hypertarget`, with two parameters of an anchor name, and anchor text. `\hyperlink` has two arguments, the name of a hypertext object defined somewhere by `\hypertarget`, and the text which be used as the link on the page.
>   *Note that in HTML parlance, the `\hyperlink` command inserts a notional `#` in front of each link, making it relative to the current testdocument; `\href` expects a full URL.*

---

Let us analyse your line:

1. You have a single closing bracket `]` between the two mandatory arguments which has no meaning.
2. The second mandatory arguments isn't closed by a curly bracket.
3. You are using a hash `#` inside your link address. So you have to declare the current frame as fragile. I guess the hash isn't part of the link address.

Based on the given information above the line should be

```
\href{https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/miller/miller.pdf}{\beamergotobutton‌​{for detail click here}}
```

---

Here a complete minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\href{https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2005-2/miller/miller.pdf}{\beamergotobutton{for detail click here}}

\href{https://www.tug.org/pracjourn#/2005-2/miller/miller.pdf#}{\beamergotobutton{for detail click here}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```